# Prove by contradiction that there is an $i \in [n]$ such that $x_i \geq 2$ if $x_1,\ldots,x_n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Prove this statement using a proof by contradiction: 
Let $n$ be a natural number. If $x_1,\ldots,x_n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i} = n+1$ then there is an $i \in [n]$ such that $x_i \geq 2$

I'm not sure how to approach this problem with the proof by contradiction. So far, I assume that there is no $i \in [n] : x_i \geq 2$. Then, $\sum_{i=1}^{1}{x_i} < 2$. Finally, because $\sum_{i=1}^{1}{x_i} = n + 1 = 2$, I can conclude that by contradiction this is false.

I'm not entirely sure if this logic is a valid proof by contradiction or what a better proof would be. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is that you are focusing only on $\sum_{i=1}^1 x_i = x_1$ to get your contradiction, but we don't know anything about this sum. The sum that we do know a lot about is $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n = n+1$, so we should try and contradict this assumption.

To be clear, the reason why we don't know anything about $\sum_{i=1}^1 x_i$ is because $n$ was given and is fixed. We don't know what the value of $n$ is, nor do we have control over what value it is, just that we *have it*

So with proof by contradiction, we would want to try to contradict some assumption or some known fact.

As you pointed out, we assume that there is no $i \in [n]$ such that $x_i \geq 2$. What's another way to say this? Well, this is saying **for every** $i \in [n], \, x_i < 2$. Now we **do** have control of this $i$, so we know that $x_i = 0,1$, as each is a nonnegative integer.

Now if we consider the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = x_1+x_2 + \cdots + x_n$, we note that each $x_i$ could equal $0$ or it could equal $1$. Obviously, the maximal possibility is that each $x_i = 1$, so we have an inequality:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = \underbrace{x_1}_{\leq 1} + \underbrace{x_2}_{\leq 1} + \cdots + \underbrace{x_n}_{\leq 1} \,\, \leq \,\, \underbrace{1 + 1 + \cdots + 1}_{n-\text{times}} = n.$$
So the sum can be at most $n$. But this is a contradiction, as we know that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = n+1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x_i\leq 1$ for all $i$, then $x_1+\ldots+x_n\leq 1+\ldots +1 = n\cdot 1 = n$.

Contraposition:
If $x_1+\ldots+x_n> n$, there is an $i$ with $x_i\geq 2$.

$P\Rightarrow Q \Leftrightarrow \neg Q\Rightarrow\neg P$.